# Runtime of for loop with array accesing

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

If i have a for-loop where for each index i access `array[i], array[i-1], array[i+1]` will it still run in O(n) assuming all of the accessing is constant?

Example:

```
for(int i=1; i<array.length-1;i++){
  if(array[i]) 
    ...
  if(array[i-1]) 
    ...
  if(array[i+1]) 
    ...
}
```

My confusion stems from the fact that seemingly we have 3 access calls, rather than the 1 to `array[i]` you normally see in the textbook examples of time-complexity.

Comment: In absolute terms you execute 3*n calls to the array. But when talking about Big-O you are interested in the asymptotic behaviour of your function (for n going to infinity). In infinite terms n and 3*n are identical therefore it is O(n)

Comment: @Scorpioo590 you should make this an answer.